# Unable to manipulate the DOM in a React component

Tags: dom, reactjs

I can't manipulate the `<div id="chart">` either in **componentWillMount** or **componentDidMount** lifecycle methods.

`document.getElementById("chart")` returns **null** in both the methods. Should I not use the raw DOM manipulation function or should I use something else to achieve the same which is manipulate the `<div id="chart">`

```
import React from 'react'

export default class D3Chart extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
         document.getElementById("chart").innerText = "Testing";
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        document.getElementById("chart").innerText = "Testing";
    }

    render() {
            return (<div id="chart"></div>
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount. `getElementById` only works on elements that are inserted in the document.

Comment: @FelixKling: Could you explain a little more, please? Your linked page doesn't mention `getElementById` or the word "insert". Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `ref` like the React guys [recommend](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class D3Chart extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.refs.chart.innerText = "Testing";
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="chart" ref="chart"></div>;
    }
}
```

And here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36941/).

Answer (score 5):

The ref is how you access the node, similar to id in HTML

```
this.refs.myDiv;

<div ref='myDiv' />
```

, and the `key` is how React differentiates between similar nodes. The method cloneElement (used for adding additional props to an instantiated JSX template) maintains these references, so you don't have to worry about "losing" your object references.

---

Also in a more complicated / different / next-gen light:

> When attaching `[ref]` to a DOM component like `<div />`, you get the DOM node back; when attaching `[ref]` to a composite component like `<TextInput />`, you'll get the React class instance. In the latter case, you can call methods on that component if any are exposed in its class definition.

```
render () {
    return (
        <div ref={htmlOrComponent => { this.htmlOrComponent = htmlOrComponent }}
    );
}

componentDidMount () {
    // this.htmlOrComponent is either the HTML or null
}
```

---